# Selenium WebDriver - Python - Simulate mouse scroll to the left/right using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

In the my test-app that's built in angular there is a table with no scrollbar containing 10-11 columns. In the default view, there would be 8 fields displayed. To view the rest of fields, the user has to either use the mouse scroll to the right to view the fields/ use keyword arrow buttons. I need to simulate this in selenium webdriver to scroll to the 11th column so that I can perform further validations. I tried to use scrollintoview function in javascript. However, since the element is not displayed without scroll, it does not work. Please note that the html table do not contain any veritical/ horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: Code trials? Relevant HTML? Error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this.

```
javaScript = "document.getElementById('any_visible_locator').scrollLeft += -250;"
driver.execute_script(javaScript)
```